# Which is correct: "the below information" or "the information below"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, above-below

I frequently see statements that refer to something later in the text that use a phrase such as "the below information". Is it more correct instead to say "the information below" (or "the following information")?

Comment: I would assume you also find "the above figure" to be a problem? I personally correct authors constantly in using these terms as adjectives.

Comment: @way0utwest: Yes, I prefer "The frame around my name in the question above is ornate." rather than "the above question."

Comment: When someone writes "the below information", I surmise that their native language is not English.

Comment: @GEdgar - Or the writer is trying to sound "businesslike", and they expect "the below information" to help them "synergise the value add".

Comment: Intuitively I feel like I can I simply use "the below" (without any further words / nouns). Is it the case? For example, can I write in a email: "let's discuss the below" ? Should I ask another question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a preposition, "below" would be written after "information" as [a stranded preposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding). While typically prepositions would precede the noun, stranded prepositions can occur "in interrogative or relative clauses, where the interrogative or relative pronoun that is the preposition's complement is moved to the start".

We see such a stranded preposition in the case of "the information below," and therefore the preposition *follows* it. By contrast, in the case of "the following information", an adjective is used to describe the noun and therefore may *precede* it.

In short, "the below information" is not generally accepted to be correct, because "below" is not universally acknowledged as an adjective. Nevertheless, some dictionaries specifically list this as an exception.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Just as "the following paragraph" is correct, the "the below information" is also correct.

Comment: Please refer to the discussion under nohat's answer: whether or not this is correct depends completely on whether or not "below" may be used as an adjective.

Comment: Stating that "the below information is incorrect" is incorrect, therefore your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Instead of repeating your opinion, a more constructive contribution to this discussion would be demonstrating that "below" is acknowledged as an adjective.

Comment: I don't see why the burden of proof should be on me. "Below" can be both. The fact that you explained it YOURSELF as a preposition is not my problem. The question should be answered with a general answer, not with a subjective answer containing false assumptions.

Comment: My answer is based upon the fact that Webster's Unabridged Dictionary, Collins English Dictionary and Wiktionary all only list "below" as a preposition and an adverb. I don't see the need to get so upset about this.

Comment: It appears that there is simply some difference definitions between dictionaries. "Below" is listed in the American Heritage as an adjective, specifically with this definition.

Comment: Whether or not word A is acknowledged as part of speech B by resource C is completely orthogonal to the question of whether or not it is actually *used* that way in sentence D. In the sentence "I belowed your betweens", neither *below* nor *between* is a preposition.

Comment: Rimmer, RegDwight: I've revised my answer based upon your comments.

Comment: Two points:1- you say "prepositions follow the noun". That is opposite of most understandings of the words in that statement. 2-adjectives can sometimes be placed after what it modifies - 'attorney general'.

Comment: @RegDwight: 'Whether or not word A is acknowledged as part of speech B by resource C is completely orthogonal to the question of whether or not it is actually used that way in sentence D.' Yes, but if they're competent descriptivists, whether or not word A is acknowledged as part of speech B by resource C is **not** completely orthogonal to the question of whether or not it is actually used that way at all.

Comment: Prepositions, by their very nature and definition, _never_ follow the noun they modify. ‘Below’ is an adverb in _the information below_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's my understanding that in the case of ["stranded" prepositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding), prepositions *can* follow the noun.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma I should have said “_directly_ follow”, I guess. With stranded prepositions, the preposition is removed entirely from its object. Yes, it follows (comes later than) the object; but it doesn’t _follow_ (come immediately after and form a unit with) the object.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Here's something to ponder: consider how you cannot swap in *below* for any adjective in **“Their eager young eyes stared at the stormy grey sea.”** Because it cannot substitute for an adjective in syntactic tests such as these without yielding an ungrammatical result, I believe that this failure provides strong evidence that *below* is **not** an adjective at all.

Comment: @tchrist To the extent that _below_ is grammatical at all preceding the noun it relates to, it can grammatically (if somewhat nonsensically) replace _stormy_ just fine to me, as can _above_. It cannot co-occur with possessive determinatives, so it cannot replace _eager_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Now I wonder whether something can be made of the curious coöccurrence restriction you mention, and perhaps also of the adjective ordering restrictions.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not actually sure if that's a grammatical restriction or just a very strong semantic one. _Below-mentioned_ (which is more unequivocally an adjective) is subject to the same restriction (“Their below-mentioned reasons” is impossible for me, at least).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I believe compound words like *above-mentioned* work like *tool-using* and *grass-fed* do, as well as like *skyscraper* and *can-opener*. In all those “aforementioned” :) cases the um non-verb portion which normally follows is reärranged to precede that verb when a compound is formed, so *mentioned above, using tools, fed grass, scraping skies, opening cans*. Germanic orders these differently from Romance, where you leave the object in the normal place; cf. FR *marque-page* for bookmark, IT *fermacarte* for paperweight, ES *rascacielos* for skyscraper.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, there's no doubt that _below_ must follow the verb in the underlying structure in compounds of this type (traditionally called _verbale Rektionskomposita_). I wasn't implying that _below-mentioned_ has any relevance to ‘the below information’, just that both fall in the adjective slot and both are completely incompatible with possessive determinatives (and perhaps other things as well).

Comment: @RiMMER I only ever see non-native English speakers use "below" as an adjective.

Answer (score 20):

An [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20below%20information,the%20information%20below&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) reveals which is more common...

[image: the below information]

Comment: +1: And [adding to the Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+below+information%2Cthe+information+below%2C+the+above+information%2C+the+information+above&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) "the information above" and "the above information" shows that while "above" can go both before and after the noun, "below" can only go after.

Comment: I see "the below information" a lot in texts that can be identified as coming from non-native speakers/those that have English as a second-language. E.g in Hindi you would use the word order"Below given information", and it seems  this influences the usage by Hindi native speakers (comparable in size to all native English users), of English as a second language .

Answer (score 14):

Merriam-Webster [lists a relevant definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/below):

> below (adjective): written or discussed lower on the same page or on a following page

Given this, there is nothing wrong with “the below information”.

Comment: I hadn't considered that it could be an adjective. Random House doesn't list it; perhaps this is where the confusion comes from?

Comment: It is at least much less widely used as an adjective than as an adverb.

Comment: I want 'below' to be used as an adjective, but I think it is not generally accepted ('bad form'), buit the position is still in question; one can have adjectives (rarely) come after the noun. But I feel that this particular 'below' is more adverbial. The M-W definition doesn't give an example and OED doesn't list an adjectival entry. The related OED entry fro 'beneath' gives the adjective as 'rare' (with a Shakespeare quote). A newspaper editor would fire a writer who tried to use "the below information", whatever ones justification might be.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't like the sound of it myself, but I think that it is becoming / will become more common / acceptable. I don't like the quote verb 'be like', but I'm resigned to its use. That the usage is cited in M-W surely 'legalises' it - absences from other respected dictionaries are not final proofs. Notice that M-W only licenses the domain of written / printed materials.

Answer (score 7):

"He lives on the below floor" or "He lives on the floor below"? -- If not grammar, at least usage is against the first mentioned way of saying it.

Comment: The MW sense for the attributive-position adjective (below {adjective}: written or discussed lower on the same page or on a following page) does not sanction domains outside the written / printed page, I'd guess in line with usage.

Comment: _He lives on the below floor_ means _He lives on the floor that we call **below**_. Like, _he lives on the top floor_ or _he lives on the ground floor_.

Answer (score -1):

Usage of the former is often seen in a corporate communication when the author wishes to add a degree of formality or authority to the explanation. For example, 'see data in the below table'. Ironic, really, as instead of adding gravitas it results in the author sounding generic and bland.

Personally, I think it sounds unnatural, and forced, as it is rarely used in speech. You'd never, for example, respond to a query as to where a physical item was in relation to another by saying it 'is on the below shelf'.

One of those phrases used in a corporate context that doesn't exist in real life.

Comment: I have no recollection of having seen the first usage. The second is common in written communication.

Comment: +1, I would agree, although *below <noun>* is wrong, in my mind, even though I am seeing it more often in (US English) technical/business/official texts. However, *above <noun>* is more corporate than *<noun> above* - see [It's ok to say “the above image” but not “the below image”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/132323/its-ok-to-say-the-above-image-but-not-the-below-image)

Answer (score -3):

The fact that the dictionary lists the word 'below' as an adjective doesn't mean it's correct. Dictionaries are a reflection of usage, both correct and incorrect. The reason that the word 'below' may be listed as an adjective reflects the overwhealming incorrect usage of the word. To make proper use of a language, one shoud use forms that have always been deemed correct and not use incorrect forms that have become the norm. Why 'dumb down' our language?

Comment: This ‘answer’ shows a staggering lack of knowledge of how language actually works. There is no such thing as “forms that have always been deemed correct”.