# Using "meantime" as an adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Does it make sense to say:

> Please consider this email as a meantime brief report.

If yes, why? and if no, how can it be fixed?

**Edit**
By the above sentence, I want to say that this email is not the main report but, in the meantime, I just want to update you about the status and I'll send you another email later.

Comment: What dictionary did you find listing *meantime* as an adjective?

Comment: You know, *above* is also not an adjective.

Comment: @tchrist: that's a great comment, but I heard it many many times. Are you too picky or is it really wrong? How should I fix it then? *"By the sentence above ..."* is OK?

Comment: @tchrist: You know better than the compilers at the AHD, Collins, Webster's, and, I'd guess, the OED, (re 'above') then?

Comment: There is a difference between standard written English and today use. You are welcome to document the heck out of all the today use you please, but if today use it not generally accepted in formal written English, then it isn’t.

Comment: And you're the one to decide on that? I've used _above_ as an adjective in the attributive position for many years, and the dictionaries cited don't label such usage as slang, colloquial, non-standard ... Websters even has a usage note: usage: A few critics object to the use of _above_ as an adjective ('the above data') or as a noun (study the above) in referring to what has been mentioned earlier in a piece of writing. Both uses, however, have long been standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: how about 'meantime'?

Comment: Just move the word ahead: ***Meanwhile** (not meantime, though), please consider this email as a brief report.*

Comment: Undue down vote, unfair close vote. How should one know for sure? cf. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110920/using-meantime-as-an-adjective#comment225073_110920

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edwin, your points are well taken, but I might respectfully suggest they are not strengthened by _ad hominem_ comments. Opinion is the life blood of this site. Each of us has a right to his or hers, no?

Comment: I'm rather fond of "stop-gap" if I may add to RD's list.  

I also think Kris had a good notion to lead with "meanwhile".  

The bigger problem might be the odd invocation of subjectivity in "please consider".  It _is_ an interim report; that fact is not up for judgement by the recipient.  I would write something to the effect of: 

"The main report is pending.* In the meantime, here's an update:"

*Bonus points if you tell them by when they can expect the full report.

Comment: Dear everyone, let's stay on-topic. Whether or not *above* is an adjective, should be, and is, addressed in [a separate question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74182/above-below-before-after-a-noun). Feel free to comment on that one, but I will be purging the comments here shortly.

Comment: @John M. Landsberg:  'Opinion is the life blood of this site. Each of us has a right to his or hers, no?' It is my opinion that, when opinions are contrary to those held by at least some authoritative bodies, it is - I'll say unhelpful - to state them as fact and without any references. The other thread conveys the correct tone.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm sorry - I've been trying to firm up this comment. At http://personal.stevens.edu/~ysakamot/creativity/carin%20dual.pdf Christina L. Gagne avers: 'An interesting feature of the English language is that any noun can be used as an adjective.' Since 'meantime' is listed as a noun (AHD, Collins etc), if Gagne is correct (and 'noun modifiers' _are_ certainly extremely common), then this usage is 'licensed'. I'd say this wouldn't convert it to an adjective. And I wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: While we're in this area, the word _hitherto_ is licensed by the OED as an attributive adjective ( http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=23716&p=84187&hilit=adjective#p84187 ). Again, that doesn't mean I'd ever use it thus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for *interim*, *preliminary*, *draft*, or *progress*. (Watch the [adjective order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order), they go after *brief*.) You are not looking for *meanwhile*, which is not an adjective, as a dictionary of your choice will be quick to point out.

Answer (score -1):

"Meantime" is a noun and an adverb, not an adjective.

As I do not understand the true meaning you are attempting to convey, I cannot provide advice on how to correct your statement.