# Why is the adjective "below" rare compared to adjective "above"?

Tags: differences, adjectives, adverbs, history, linguistics

*Above* and *below* can be used as both an adverb and an adjective to indicate an earlier or a later part of a piece of writing respectively. However, adjective *below* is rare compared to adjective *above* (and mostly not a preferred usage).

*OED* definitions of the adjective forms:

above:

> Mentioned, described, listed, etc., further up on the present page or previously in the text. Cf. above-mentioned *adj.*

Last two citations from *OED*:

> 1959        A. Arnold *D. H. Lawrence & Amer.* ii. 24          Ten days after the above letter was written, Lawrence learnt of the suppression of The Rainbow by the English authorities.
>
> 1990       T. Cunliffe *Easy on Helm* xiv. 120          Should you be faced with the above horror show.., you'll have to use the single controlling line technique.

below:

> Mentioned, described, listed, etc., further down on the present page, or subsequently in the text. Cf. below-mentioned *adj.* 
>       <sub>*rare* in comparison with above *adj.*</sub>

Last two citations from *OED*:

> 1996        *Frank* 8 May 3/3        David's many Canadian admirers are invited to visit he and Danielle..at the below address.
>
> 2016        M. Sofiev & M. Prank in P. J. Beggs I*mpacts of Climate Change on Allergens & Allergic Dis.* iv. 53       In the below analysis, we shall..make some basic statistics based on meteorological past-time data.

---

<sup>There is also the noun usage of *above* and *below* (with "the") with a similar definition.</sup>

<sup>*OED* definitions:</sup>

<sup>above:</sup>

> <sup>Chiefly *formal*. With *the*: the preceding passage, paragraph, etc.; the person, thing, or set of things mentioned or discussed in the preceding passage, paragraph, etc.</sup>

<sup>below:</sup>

> <sup>Chiefly *formal*. With *the*: the following passage, paragraph, etc.; the person, thing, or set of things mentioned or discussed in the following passage, paragraph, etc. 
>
>      <sub>*rare* in comparison with above n. 3.</sub></sup>

---

Why is the adjective "below" rare compared to adjective "above"? (the noun usage also)

Would it be possible to find a historical reason? Could it be related to how frequently they appeared in publications or influential works? Or, could it be related to the distribution of the adverb senses?

Comment: Could it be because people normally read documents from beginning to end, so referring to points above makes sense because the reader has already seen those points? Whereas referring to points below is generally more applicable in cases like your examples where the reference is made in an introduction.

Comment: Note that referring to points *below* is quite common in email communication because email programs position new replies above the text of the previous email. Long email chains are pretty common in business and government work, but aren't usually made public so aren't available for study or inclusion in word usage statistics.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74182/above-below-before-after-a-noun?rq=1 . It's more usual to say 'the address below'.

Comment: because saying stuff as 'the below analysis' provokes a response in many native English speakers worse than when they hear a chalkboard screeched... it simply sounds terrible... because it's not actually an adjective

Comment: @nnnnnn: Interesting approach. I don't think it is related to how we read, it is just used to indicate the position of a text. Introductory/summary statements are quite common and it is not the only place to use it. I appreciate that you are trying to find a reasoning. In your second comment, I believe you meant the adverb usage.

Comment: @green_ideas: There is the adjective usage of _below_ but it is rare. It might not sound natural to most as it is rare. However, it is directly comparable to the more common adjective _above_. I'm trying to find a historical/linguistic reason behind this as it is a just a word referring to a position.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yes, I've read that question and I'm asking the historical/linguistic reason behind it.

Comment: because resistance to the adjectival usage of 'below' is still strong enough from enough quarters to impede such usage, whereas similar, strong initial resistance to the adjectival use of 'above' has largely been overcome by popular usage...which might well be the fate of 'adjectival below' as well, the argument by analogy being no small thing, in the minds of both non-native and native speakers. come back in 25 years, and then 50, to see how this answer, which posits historical usage, is valid ;) again, it's rare, because to most native speakers it sounds jarring

Comment: you can trace initial, very strong resistance to adjectival above to its begrudging acceptance to larger acceptance in the usage notes of dictionaries, say those of the 50s, 80s, and 2010s... thus I surmise and have done so for awhile, that adjectival below is in the early stages of this process