# "Country + Market" & "Nationality + Market"

Tags: word-usage

The title says it all, recently I was asked by a co-worker if the below sentence is correct:

> ... are not provided on products for the **Japanese** market

Typically, a standard usage should be:

> ... are not provided on products for the **Japan** market

So can we combine country's nationality with the word "market" and the outcome still has the same meaning as "Country + Market"?

Comment: The question is not correct; "the below sentence" is an error.  It is not correct to use "below" as an adjective.  English Language Learners is a good site for learners.  On "the below sentence," see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below/130007#130007

Comment: @Xanne this is a case of prescriptive vs descriptive usage. Just like *above sentence*. Dictionary usage panels hated *above* when it was first started being used in that way. Given time, *below sentence* will start to sound normal, ie, be grammatical. (The usage hurts my ears but can't contain language change.) Also, non-native speakers use it by way of analogy with *above*. Which is what we'd expect good language learners to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes “Japanese market” is correct.  But not because “Japanese” as a descriptor of a type of person (nationality) but simply from the meaning ‘of Japan’ (adjective).

To see the distinction more clearly, it would be “Finnish market”, not “Finn market”.

In fact, “Japan market” is more of a shorthand that a rather technical writer (for a finance mag, for example) might want to use.

Comment: I expect by 'simply from the meaning 'of Japan'" you mean that it is the adjective of Japan. As is, your sentence doesn't quite make sense or really argue anything. I agree that Japanese is correct 'not because "Japanese" is a descriptor of a type of person' but because Japanese is the adjective for Japan

Comment: @Unrelated Yes, I mean the adjective. Thanks. Edited